# Programs that may block other Processes

Tags: windows

So I'm having some difficulty with a program that I use for a game. I'm not asking for help to fix this program, but rather how can I tell what other processes may block this program from properly being used.

Here's the issue:
I'm trying to run the PunkBuster services on my computer in order to play BattleField 3, and for these services to run properly they have 2 programs, PnkBstrA and PnkBstrB, in which PnkBstrA starts PnkBstrB, however for some reason there is something that is blocking PnkBstrA from PnkBstrB. I've talked with the support team for this and they are telling me that there is something on my computer doing this, not a fault in their software.

However, I've disabled everything I can Imagine that would cause this. I've disabled Microsoft Security Essentials (Firewall and Defender) and I don't run any third party antivirus outside of AntiMalware bytes.

My Computer:
Windows 8.1 Lenovo All-in-One basically. So is there something else on my computer that might be stopping PnkBstr from doing what it needs to do, even though I have everything turned down, even my User Access is turned low. I have no idea what could be causing this but they keep insisiting that it is something.

Comment: When you say "something that is blocking PnkBstrA from PnkBstrB" it means PnkBstrB process is not starting at all? Or it's starting but there is no communication between processes? Anyhow, it's kind of strange that you have a process blocked without notice. Have you checked EventLog?

Comment: It starts but there is no communication it seems. I have checked in the Event Viewer and nothing seemed out of the ordinary. It just kept saying PnkBstrB was installed, which is what PnkBstrA is supposed to do.

Comment: If there is no log message you won't be able to know what's going on. And I don't think it's something in your Windows but more like a bug in the software.

Comment: All it states in the Event Log under System was that PnkBstrB was installed and gives no further information on anything. Is that how it's supposed to be? Here's an example:

A service was installed in the system.

Service Name:  PnkBstrB
Service File Name:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\PnkBstrB.exe
Service Type:  user mode service
Service Start Type:  auto start
Service Account:  LocalSystem

Comment: That looks like a message from the installation process. Applications should report error to the user, services should log errors to event log. I asked you to check to see if there was something there. Usually Windows applications are poorly programmed and don't have a good error reporting. If the application doesn't tell you what's wrong, you will have a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Yeah there is nothing that I could find, but thank you for the help. I also agree that it seems like a bug in the software itself, but they are of no help. You've been plenty help in answering my question.